# What is causing a "Delay" in updating state in Redux?

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm struggling to understand what I'm doing wrong with the below Redux & React native code.

I'm trying to create a workout tracking app where a user can input their workout progress. I've created a 'workoutSessionSlice' to keep track of the state.

```
const initialState: IWorkoutSessionState = {
  currentTrackingEquipment: {
    createdOn: { seconds: 0, nanoseconds: 0 },
    equipmentName: '',
    repetitions: [],
    results: [],
    repetitionIndex: 0,
  },
  hasRunningSession: false,
  isTrackingEquipment: false,
  savedSessionEquipmentRecords: [],
};

export const workoutSessionSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'workoutSession',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    saveEquipmentRecord: (
      state: any,
      action: PayloadAction<IEquipmentRecord>,
    ) => {
      state.savedSessionEquipmentRecords.push(action.payload);
    },
    addResult: (state: any, action: PayloadAction<IRepResult>) => {
      state.currentTrackingEquipment.results[
        state.currentTrackingEquipment.repetitionIndex
      ] = action.payload;
    },
    updateRepIndex: (state: any, action: PayloadAction<number>) => {
      state.currentTrackingEquipment.repetitionIndex = action.payload;
    },
  },
});
```

The user uses a certain piece of equipment and adds the result of each repetition to the state via a button. I've noticed that there is a 'delay' on the state as I console.log the payload and the state in the function of this button:

```
const handleAddRep = (success: boolean, nextRepIndex: boolean) => {

    console.log({
      repetitions:
        workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.results[
          workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.repetitionIndex
        ].repetitions,
      weight: equipmentTracking.wheelPickerValue,
      success,
    });

    dispatch(
      addResult({
        repetitions:
          workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.results[
            workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.repetitionIndex
          ].repetitions,
        weight: equipmentTracking.wheelPickerValue,
        success,
      }),
    );

    console.log(workOutSession);
  };
```

console:

```
Object {
  "repetitions": 15,
  "success": true,
  "weight": 100,
}

Object {
  "currentTrackingEquipment": Object {
    "createdOn": Object {
      "nanoseconds": 735000000,
      "seconds": 1671364848,
    },
    "equipmentName": "Bench-press-incline",
    "repetitionIndex": 0,
    "repetitions": Array [
      15,
      12,
      7,
    ],
    "results": Array [
      Object {                  // expected this object to be replaced
        "repetitions": 15,
        "success": false,
        "weight": 0,
      },
      Object {
        "repetitions": 12,
        "success": false,
        "weight": 0,
      },
      Object {
        "repetitions": 7,
        "success": false,
        "weight": 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  "hasRunningSession": true,
  "isTrackingEquipment": true,
  "savedSessionEquipmentRecords": Array [],
}
```

When I log the state manually outside of the function of the button, I do see the correct data in the array & object:

```
Object {
  "currentTrackingEquipment": Object {
    "createdOn": Object {
      "nanoseconds": 735000000,
      "seconds": 1671364848,
    },
    "equipmentName": "Bench-press-incline",
    "repetitionIndex": 1,
    "repetitions": Array [
      15,
      12,
      7,
    ],
    "results": Array [
      Object {
        "repetitions": 15,
        "success": true,
        "weight": 100,
      },
      Object {
        "repetitions": 12,
        "success": false,
        "weight": 0,
      },
      Object {
        "repetitions": 7,
        "success": false,
        "weight": 0,
      },
    ],
  },
  "hasRunningSession": true,
  "isTrackingEquipment": true,
  "savedSessionEquipmentRecords": Array [],
}
```

The problem is that this 'delay' also happens when I want save the record, resulting in the last object in the results array to not be updated.

```
onPress={() => {
  Alert.alert('Successfully finished rep?', undefined, [
    {
      text: 'Yes',
      onPress: () => {
        if (
          workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment
            .repetitionIndex ===
          workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.results.length - 1
        ) {
          handleAddRep(true, false);  // Should update rep in "currentTrackingEquipment"
          Alert.alert('Finished tracking equipment?', undefined, [
            {
              text: 'Yes',
              onPress: () => {
                handleFinishEquipmentTracking(); // adds current tracking equipment to "savedSessionEquipmentRecords"
              },
            },
            {
              text: 'No, go back',
            },
          ]);
        } else {
          handleAddRep(true, true);
        }
      },
    },
  ]);
}}
```

I've tried setting the values at the object keys instead of replacing the entire object, but that didn't work as well. Any help will be appreciated!

**Solved! thanks to Phry**.

Below is what I changed to make this work:
I the above code I call "handleFinishEequipmentTracking" which looked like this:

```
const handleFinishEquipmentTracking = () => {
  dispatch(
    saveEquipmentRecord({
      createdOn: workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.createdOn,
      equipmentName: workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.equipmentName,
      repetitions: workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.repetitions,
      results: workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.results,
      repetitionIndex:
        workOutSession.currentTrackingEquipment.repetitionIndex,
    }),
  );
};
```

The object given as parameter in "saveEquipmentRecord" is, as Phry explained, a local variable and will not update when the state is changed by "handleAddRep". I had to make a two simple changes in the "saveEquipmentRecord" function:

```
const handleFinishEquipmentTracking = () => {
  dispatch(saveEquipmentRecord());
};
```

And in the reducer I changed that the source of data for the saved equipmentRecords is the state itself and not a copy of the state in a local variable:

from:

```
saveEquipmentRecord: (
  state: any,
  action: PayloadAction<IEquipmentRecord>,
) => {
  state.savedSessionEquipmentRecords.push(action.payload);
},
```

to:

```
saveEquipmentRecord: (state: any) => {
  state.savedSessionEquipmentRecords.push(state.currentTrackinEquipment);
},
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "delay" - you are looking at old ("stale") data that will never get updated.

See this example:

```js
let state = { foo: 1 }
const s = state
state = { foo: 2 }
// s is now { foo: 1 } and state is { foo: 2 }
```

Just because your state updates to a new value (and it will be a completely new object, since state updates are immutable) doesn't mean your local variables will update - they will still point at the same value they did before.

In the future, that component will rerender - and then `const something = useSelector(...)` will re-execute. And then you have a new variable with that same name and that new variable will have the new value (but soon again, run stale).

Comment: Yes, this was it! Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :). I'll describing what exactly solved it for if anyone reads this in the future.